# Which Service Applications are Required?

Tags: 2013, service-application, service

I'm looking to upgrade our 800-person Intranet from SharePoint (Standard) 2010 to 2013. It is a publishing site, with a single site collection and consists of two servers only, Web server and Database server.

What are the minimum Service Applications that need to be enabled? Cannot find this info on TechNet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer obtained here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/8a3f3bdf-7302-4203-84b2-81c7abbd12c2/which-service-applications-are-required

Central Administration

Managed Metadata Web Service

Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application

Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Workflow Timer Service