# Which Service Application Databases are Mandatory in Upgrade to 2013?

Tags: publishing-site, user-profile-service, upgrade

I have checked [TechnNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee731990.aspx) and posted a [related question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76960/which-service-applications-are-required) but still cannot find a simple answer for this.

I am upgrading from SharePoint 2010 to 2013 standard. It's a two-server farm for an internal publishing site. We do not use My Sites or use any of the "social" assets. I now have a legacy content DB (zero errors with Test-SPContentDatabase) prepared but need to attend to the task of copying over and attaching service databases first. What are the minimum "required" services that need to be configured and have their databases attached in new farm? In particular, do I need to bother with User Profile service since we are not using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, there is no clear answer to it...it depends!

Secondly, why would you care migrating the service applications like User Profile since you will not be using it in future?

User profiles service application is combination of Social tagging DB + Profile DB + Sync DB so consider SharePoint applications (Content Databases) which are dependent upon User Profiles, Managed Metadata or any other service application? If such is the case, then it is worth upgrading them.

Also remember, User Profile service application relies on:

- Managed metadata service (managed metadata and share content types)
- Search Service application (People search)
- Business Connectivity Services (optional for external systems)

Lycka till: Good luck as we say it in Swedish :)

Comment: Thanks for answering Falak. I'm trying to determine if ANY of these service DB's are mandatory. So I do not need to migrate user profile DB?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct

Comment: What about Managed Metadata and Search? I have a single site collection/Web application and don't mind re-indexing since upgrading in non-production environment...

Comment: I would say provisioning the new Search application and Managed Medatadata is a great idea. You can easily build the new index with Search service.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the MMS in your Publishing Site? I have never done a publishing project without some use of MMS, as a result, you need to upgrade MMS along with your publishing site or you will orphan the terms.

As for search, have you created any Managed Properties that you wish to retain? If so you need a plan for upgrading those.

Comment: Thanks for feedback Mathew. We are basically using defaults and have not had reason so far to avail of customization via Metadata and Managed Properties. That said, I'm going to upgrade the MMS DB and configure it just in case. To utilize Managed Properties, which search service DB's need to be copied over and attached?

Comment: The storage of Managed Properties changes in 2013. The properties are no longer in the Search Properties DB they are stored in the index. I am not certain if the upgrade even picks then up. It is easy, however, to use PowerShell to enumerate the Managed Properties and recreate them in 2013.